# How to get product image height & width in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-images

In my product gallery code I am displaying several product images. I would like to specify each image's height & width in the img tag. How can I get each image's height & width programatically in Magento (without using getimagesize)?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the pixel dimensions in Windows File Explorer.
Just select the 'Details pane' under the 'View' tab.

[image]

Then select the image. The pixel dimensions will show in the display panel.
[image]

Comment: To clarify, I need to get the dimensions programmatically in Magento.